# Subversion client which shows history and branches graphically

Tags: windows, gratis, subversion

I do like [PLasticSCM](https://www.plasticscm.com) as a version control system, mainly because of its great GUI.

It can show me things like this 
[image]

(and that's not a particularly impressive example)

to allow me quickly to have a visual overview of the version history including branching.

I am looking for a similar client for Subversion, gratis for commercial use, running on Windows, although cross platform would be a bonus.

Comment: Maybe you can find something useful [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13039/is-there-a-tool-that-can-display-a-svn-repository-visually-i-e-pretty-charts) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Subversion_clients). My first guess was going to be TortoiseSVN, which has a clunky-looking but possibly serviceable revision graph, but I don't use it (or any other SVN client) personally.

Comment: Despite that question being 9 years old, it has some good links!  The Subversion [revision graph](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/images/RevisionGraph.png) looks good. Not graphically slick, but the information is there.

Comment: See also [this old S.O question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308/graphical-representation-of-svn-branch-merge-activity) has some good mentions (and pretty pictures)